# App rejected: SDK: Cardinal Commerce org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk (consider upgrading to version 2.2.7-2)

Tags: react-native, google-play, braintree

My app getting rejected.

package.json:

"react-native": "0.72.6",
"react-native-braintree-dropin-ui": "1.1.5",

I tried to add this line inside

app/build.gradle:

`implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:6.11.0'`

I also tried

`implementation 'org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.7-2'`

but it still getting rejected.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading helped me resolve the issue.

"react-native-braintree-dropin-ui": "^1.1.1",